# Using parameters for directives of warngler

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

In a cloud datafusion wrangler I can perform multiple transformation using directives. The scenario that i am looking into is there are a set of directives which might change with each execution.

for e.g.

some-directives
.
.
set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)}
hash concat_col SHA-256 true
.
.
some-other-directives

I want to parameterize the part of the directive. I used the below steps

some-directives
.
.
${custom_directive}
.
.
some-other-directives

This works if i pass only 1 directive as the parameter value i.e. set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)}

However when i try to pass more than 1 directive the pipeline fails.

I have tried the below formats for the parameter value

set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)};hash concat_col SHA-256 true
throws an error expected column name but got an identifier

set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)}\r\nhash concat_col SHA-256 true
pipeline fails with the error expecting ; but got \r

set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)} \r\nhash concat_col SHA-256 true
succeeds but does not perform the hash

"set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)}\r\nhash concat_col SHA-256 true"
pipeline succeeds but doesn't perform both the steps

set-column :concat_col exp:{concat(col1,col2)},hash concat_col SHA-256 true
pipeline fails with the error expected ; but got ,

Is there a way i can pass multiple lines of directives to a single parameter?

Comment: Depending in you pipeline, you can use the Argument Setter in DataFusion. According tot the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/reusable-pipeline) you can use it to create a reusable pipeline and change the arguments such as directives. Is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: yes i saw the example to create a reusable pipeline, but the example there there is only a single line of directive, in general the wrangler recipe will have multiple lines of directives.
What i am looking for is how do i pass more than 1 directive to a single parameter in the recipie

Comment: Trishit Ghosh: Can you try separating the directives by newline and pass it as single runtime argument via argument setter?

Comment: Ajai: I have tried separating the directives with newline using the below separators
"/r/n" -> This is what i can see in the pipeline json export, so this was the first thing i tried but the error i get is mentioned in the issue description. expected a ; but got \r
"/n" -> used just the newline character, got the same error
tried to copy the directives with newline from a notepad -> Failed with syntax error on a "," I use in the directive 

Please note that i am currently not using an argument setter, I am just passing the value as a runtime argument

Comment: @TrishitGhosh, can you try using the Argument setter?

Comment: Argument setter is not an option for me, in any case what difference would an argument setter make in comparison to providing values to the parameters at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Supplying multiple directives to a single parameter in the wrangler works if we send the parameters via HTTP request. each line of directive needs to be separated by a \r\n character.

Strangely it does not not work when we manually enter the values in the runtime args